# How to add child data to user in Firebase using React and retrieve that data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm probably not going to explain this well as it's all a mess in my head, but I have a list of items in my React app that I want people to be able to mark as a favorite. When that person goes to their profile, they will be able to see a list of the items that they have favorited. So when I reference it I essentially want `users.currentUser.favorites`.

I'm not sure exactly how to specifically add "favorites" as a child of the current user (authenticated with Firebase), or how to grab it and update it when a new item is "favorited".

Database Structure I am going for except I'd like the user to have a "favoritePokemon" list:
[image]

I've tried adding the list to the current logged in user, but when I try to specify the current logged in user with `var myUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;` it says that "currentUser" is undefined so I'm not sure exactly how I'm supposed to target the data for that user.

Setting current user in my App.js

```
componentWillMount() {
    let data = jsonData.data.results;
    let id = 0;
    data.forEach(item => {
      id = id + 1;
      item.id = id;
    });
    this.setState({
      allPokemonData: data.slice(0, 151),
    });
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(currentUser => {
      this.setState({ currentUser });
    });
  }
```

Passing currentUser as props to my component:

```
render() {
const { allPokemonData, currentUser } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="app-wrapper">
    <Header currentUser={currentUser} />
    <Route 
      exact 
      path="/" 
      component={Home} 
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/allpokemon"
      render={props => <PokemonList allPokemon={allPokemonData} currentUser={currentUser} />}
    />
    <Route
      exact
      path={`/pokemon/:id`}
      render={props => <PokemonDetails {...props} allPokemon={allPokemonData} />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/profile"
      render={props => <Profile currentUser={currentUser} />}
    />
  </div>
)
```

}

After that I was trying to set the reference in my component:

```
if (this.props.currentUser) {
   this.usersRef = database.ref('users/' + this.props.currentUser.uid);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a "users" node in your database structure? Does the "users" node have a "favorites" child node? What have you tried in terms of [lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) such as [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) or `.set()` to add the "favorite" to the respective user's "favorites" child list of data? You need to please clarify how you are managing users within your React application as well as how your RTDB structure looks like. I'd include your database rules as well.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post with some more info. I'm having trouble representing it well because this is an area that I don't understand well.

Comment: Are you currently saving the user id when the user logs in or signs up in something like state? Are you using onAuthStateChanged() to track the user authenticating and logging out? [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users). If you save the id, you can use that to access the database properties you mention in your question. currentUser may return undefined depending on when it’s called, onAuthStateChanged can be more reliable for identifying and storing key data such as the uid for use on queries.

Comment: I was going to have it add the user id to the database when someone logs in using their Google login. I'm using onAuthStateChanged() to fire when someone logs in or logs out. I was having currentUser set with onAuthStateChanged() and passing it as props to my component, but I couldn't figure out how to set up the database reference based on the user id since props doesn't seem to load before the database call. I suppose I could set up another onAuthStateChanged() and set the database reference value then.

Comment: You need to update your question with how you are setting currentUser and passing it to your components as well as where exactly you are making this attempt to access the uid and similar data. That being said, yeah, you need to make sure the database call isn’t ever made when the user isn’t logged in. That for example you redirect to login page/form if the user logs out. Without the code it’s difficult to help.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for being patient with me. I've updated it with the code now. Here is the repository as well if you want to see the rest: https://github.com/SilasOtoko/custom-pokedex